# SQL Server : using one Select statement with 2 conditions

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I have the following SQL query, and I would need it to run `SELECT` statement only once.

May I know what are the changes I should make?

**EDIT:** Need to change to use only one `SELECT` statement..

```
DECLARE
@lang varchar(2) ='en',
@hideInactiveCompany integer = 0

IF @hideInactiveCompany = 1
SELECT <all columns>
  FROM Config.BusinessUnit BU
  LEFT JOIN Config.Organization CO on BU.OrganizationId = CO.OrganizationId
  LEFT JOIN Config.ParentBusinessUnit PBU on BU.ParentBusinessUnitId = PBU.ParentBusinessUnitId 
  WHERE BU.IsActive = 1 --the additional condition if @hideInactiveCompany=1
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN @lang = 'cn' THEN BU.Lang END,
           CASE WHEN @lang = 'en' THEN BU.Lang END DESC, 
           EntityName
ELSE
SELECT <all columns>
  FROM Config.BusinessUnit BU
  LEFT JOIN Config.Organization CO on BU.OrganizationId = CO.OrganizationId
  LEFT JOIN Config.ParentBusinessUnit PBU on BU.ParentBusinessUnitId = PBU.ParentBusinessUnitId 
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN @lang = 'cn' THEN BU.Lang END,
           CASE WHEN @lang = 'en' THEN BU.Lang END DESC, 
           EntityName
```

---

> If @hideInactiveCompany = 1, display output with BU.IsActive =1
>
> If @hideInactiveCompany = 0, display output without BU.IsActive
>   filter.

Comment: you can't use `IF ELSE` in a query.  Should use a `CASE` statement

Comment: Also , why there is a `WHERE` in the `ORDER BY` clause ?

Comment: I might have put the `WHERE` clause in the wrong place. It should in somewhere else.

Comment: I'd like to see some sample data which explains what your sorting logic is.  Your current `ORDER BY` code is a mess, probably can be simplified, but we need to see some data.

Comment: I updated my code to the original query. And at the bottom is the additional condition that I would like to put in.

Comment: How about if you use Store Procedure for every condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i do understand your requirement correctly, the entire query should have only one single SELECT clause

```
DECLARE
    @lang varchar(2) ='en',
    @hideInactiveCompany integer = 0

SELECT    <all columns>
FROM      Config.BusinessUnit BU
LEFT JOIN Config.Organization CO on BU.OrganizationId = CO.OrganizationId
LEFT JOIN Config.ParentBusinessUnit PBU on BU.ParentBusinessUnitId = PBU.ParentBusinessUnitId 
WHERE     (@hideInactiveCompany = 1 AND BU.IsActive = 1)
OR        (@hideInactiveCompany <> 1)
ORDER BY   CASE WHEN @lang = 'cn' THEN BU.Lang END,
           CASE WHEN @lang = 'en' THEN BU.Lang END DESC, 
           EntityName
```

Explanation on `WHERE`
Basically there are only 2 conditions:-

- Condition 1 : `@hideInactiveCompany = 1 AND BU.IsActive = 1`
- Condition 2 : `@hideInactiveCompany <> 1`

Condition 1 is as what you specified. When variable `@hideInactiveCompany` is 1, IsActive must be 1

Condition 2 is when variable `@hideInactiveCompany` not equal to 1

Comment: Thanks. But the output stayed the same regardless of `@hideInactiveCompany` declared as `1` or `0`. If it is `0`, the query will run without the filter of `BU.IsActive`.

Comment: But when `@hideInactiveCompany=0`, the output still display companies whose `BU.IsActive=1`

Comment: you didn't mention you wanted any other condition when `@hideInactiveCompany=0` at all. So you will get all condition of `IsActive` . See your `ELSE` section of the query that you posted

Comment: can request you to explain abit on your WHERE and OR clause?

Comment: if i were to do testing, which variable for @hideInactiveCompany should I change? The declared one, or the one inside WHERE clause? Thank you

Comment: change the value in the declare to  `@hideInactiveCompany integer = 0` or `@hideInactiveCompany integer = 1`

Answer (score 3):

We can try writing the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    (hideInactiveCompany = 1  AND BU.IsActive IS NOT NULL) OR
    (hideInactiveCompany IS NULL AND BU.IsActive IS NULL) OR
    (hideInactiveCompany <> 1)
```

Note: The OP has since changed the question a few times after I answered.  The latest answer appears to be this:

```
WHERE
    (hideInactiveCompany = 1 AND BU.IsActive = 1) OR
    hideInactiveCompany IS NULL OR hideInactiveCompany <> 1
```

Comment: May I know what do you mean? I feel I will be using `SELECT` statement for each of the `WHERE` clause, am I right?

Comment: I...I just...I don't know what to say to you at this point.  You now have 2 (3?) different questions in your question.  This answers the first one.

Comment: My apologies. I edited my question as I felt that I explained it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such a "conditionally build my select" in SQL. You need to write the complete select query twice, one for each branch of the `if`.

(SQL is generally not a "composable" langauge, you cannot freely combine the elements how you want.)

You might be able to use `case` and other expressions to rebuild in a single query, or doing the common part of the query into a temporary table (or table valued variable) and then only the final part twice.

Comment: I tried to implement 2 select statements. But when I tried to update my existing smart object in K2 Workflow, it prompt an error due to duplicated entities..

Comment: I am trying to build using CASE at the moment. Will update the post as soon as I can.

Comment: It seems like simple boolean logic is all that's required here "these conditions are true OR these conditions are true", etc. I don't know why people are so keen to jump to `CASE` with SQL.

Comment: I think I need to use CASE as I cannot use SELECT statement of each variables more than once. My apologies if I am mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Use IF ELSE condition:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Config].[usp_ListBusinessUnit] 
@lang VARCHAR(2) = NULL,
@hideInactiveCompany INTEGER
AS
BEGIN


IF @hideInactiveCompany=1
    SELECT <all columns>
    FROM Config.BusinessUnit BU
    LEFT JOIN Config.Organization CO ON BU.OrganizationId = CO.OrganizationId
    LEFT JOIN Config.ParentBusinessUnit PBU ON BU.ParentBusinessUnitId = 
PBU.ParentBusinessUnitId 
    WHERE BU.IsActive IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @lang = 'cn' THEN BU.Lang END,
        CASE WHEN @lang = 'en' THEN BU.Lang END DESC, 
        EntityName

ELSE

   SELECT <all columns>
    FROM Config.BusinessUnit BU
    LEFT JOIN Config.Organization CO ON BU.OrganizationId = CO.OrganizationId
    LEFT JOIN Config.ParentBusinessUnit PBU ON BU.ParentBusinessUnitId = 
PBU.ParentBusinessUnitId 
    WHERE BU.IsActive IS NULL
    ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @lang = 'cn' THEN BU.Lang END,
    CASE WHEN @lang = 'en' THEN BU.Lang END DESC, 
    EntityName

END
```

Comment: Thanks. However I need to run SELECT statement for each variable only once, as I am hitting duplicated entities when tying this stored procedure to my K2 service object..

Comment: `I need to run SELECT statement for each variable only once`. can you explain

Comment: I mean like to run `SELECT` statement once, and using the variables for conditions later on. In your query there are 2 `SELECT` statements. This method works, but it is not implementable in K2 Workflow ServiceObjects as they register all entities under all `SELECT` statements in the query.